# CLLocationManager error margin

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gps, cllocationmanager

Im developing a location based application for a football stadium.

I must pre define several locations on the map for the user and guide the user to that location.

Do anyone know what is the error margin in `CLLocationManager` current use location

Comment: Do you mean `CLLocation.horizontalAccuracy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the Accuracy Constant you set. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html):

> **kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation**
>
> Use the highest possible accuracy and combine it with additional
>   sensor data. This level of accuracy is intended for use in navigation
>   applications that require precise position information at all times
>   and are intended to be used only while the device is plugged in.
>   Available in OS X v10.7 and later. Declared in CLLocation.h.
>
> **kCLLocationAccuracyBest**
>
> Use the highest-level of accuracy. Available in OS X v10.6 and later.
>   Declared in CLLocation.h.
>
> **kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters**
>
> Accurate to within ten meters of the desired target. Available in OS X
>   v10.6 and later. Declared in CLLocation.h.
>
> kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
>
> Accurate to within one hundred meters. Available in OS X v10.6 and
>   later. Declared in CLLocation.h.
>
> **kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer**
>
> Accurate to the nearest kilometer. Available in OS X v10.6 and later.
>   Declared in CLLocation.h.
>
> **kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers**
>
> Accurate to the nearest three kilometers. Available in OS X v10.6 and
>   later. Declared in CLLocation.h.

**UPDATE:**

[Here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/275476-iphone-cllocation-accuracy.html) is a bit more information about its accuracity

Comment: This does notvanswer his question, erroe margin!

Comment: @AlexWien It does give Error margins. If you read the definitions the error margins are 3Km. 1Km. 10m. best (probably better than 10m.) and best for navigation (probably better than 10 m + uses more sensors than just GPS)

Comment: The error margin for "best" is missing, and a margin is only of use when you specify the probability that this margin is not exceeded.

Comment: Interesting is the difference between "nearest10" and "best". from gps view, only DGPS (WAAS and EGNOS) can be the cause, or the fact that iphone3GS general worse GPS performance is somewhere in te range of nearest10

Comment: The accurav in the link you gave is outdated, probably related to iphone3GS. And they ate no experts on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `kCLLOcationAccuracyBest` and you have a good view to open sky, you will get 3-6m positional accuracy in 95% of measures. if you have bad view, up to 30m can happen.

This is the best what you can achieve. The iphone has one of the best GPS modules (if not the best at all in consumer devices). But best is to try it out. I am not sure if the GPS receives good signals through the partial roof of the stadium. the bigger the stadium the better the view to sky which gives better accuracy.

Use a GPS App which supports waypoints, and set some waypoints.

Do the same 1 hour later, and compare the distance error. (or try to view in google maps)

Comment: +1 because I do not see any reason for a downvote. Where does this information come from?

Comment: @simpleBob the info for the error margin is the typical error of a standard GPS device, which i have proofed ro be in that range (you can download datasheets of GPS chips, but they are a bit more optimistic). the rest is info from me, GPS accuracy is my job.